# Docker Compose: Requests between containers don't work in browser

Tags: angular, typescript, docker, express, docker-compose

I have set up three services in Docker Compose: A `frontend` (built with Angular 11), a `backend` and a `dataservice` (both built with Typescript/Express).
The frontend sends requests to the backend, which in turn calls the data service to answer the request.
This works when I run it on localhost, and it works when I execute the API calls with curl from within the containers.
But when I try to run this in Docker and access the frontend with Firefox or Chrome, I receive an error message: Either `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` (Chrome) or `CORS request did not succeed` (Firefox).

I cannot figure out why this happens. Something connected to pre-flight CORS requests made by Angular?
How can I make this work?

---

The issue in more detail:

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  frontend:
    build: ../frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
  backend:
    build: ../backend
  dataservice:
    build: ../dataservice
```

The Angular **frontend** calls the backend, which exposes an API on default port `80`:

```
...
// Frontend service handling communication with the backend:

export class BackendService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(): {
    return this.http.get('http://backend/api/data');
  }
}
...
```

The **backend** in turn calls the data service, which also exposes an API on port `80`. The backend then sends the data service's response back to the frontend:

```
...
export class BackendController {

  // Called on GET http://backend/api/data:

  const getData = async(req, res): {
    const dataserviceResponse = await axios.get('http://dataservice/api/data');
    res.status(200).send(dataserviceResponse.data);
  }
}
...
```

The following things **work perfectly fine**:

- Running everything on `localhost` (without Docker Compose). For this, I assigned different ports (data service on `localhost:3000`, backend on `localhost:3001`, frontend on `localhost:4200`) and replaced `http://dataservice` with `http://localhost:3000` and `http://backend` with `http://localhost:3001`. I can access the frontend and everything works as it should, both in Firefox and Chrome.
- Pinging the Docker containers. I can connect to the frontend container (via `docker exec -it frontend_container sh`) and execute `ping backend` and `ping dataservice` successfully.
- Sending the requests with `curl`. I can connect to the frontend container and execute `curl --location --request GET 'http://backend/api/data'` successfully.

The following **does not work**:

- When I run everything on Docker Compose (as described above) and access the frontend via `http://localhost:80`, I receive an error message.

  - On Chrome, the error message is `Http failure response for http://backend/api/data: 0 Unknown Error, GET http://backend/api/data net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.
  - On Firefox, the error message is `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://backend/api/data. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`

I cannot figure out why everything works on localhost or with curl, but refuses to work on Docker inside my browsers.

Comment: The Angular code isn't running inside the Docker network, it's running in your browser. That curl doesn't work *outside* the container, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular runs in the browser. It doesn't know anything about the docker network, that is why the browser is not able to resolve the given url (backend/api/data). So when you want to send a request to the back-end from the front-end you should give the back-end's IP with its exposed port. Basically if you run everything on localhost then:

```
http://localhost:<exposed port>/api/data
```

You should expose a port for the back-end in the docker-compose file not for the front-end.